# How to get the current font size of an ace editor?

Tags: ace-editor

Ace Editor has a `setFontSize` method, but no `getFontSize`. How can I get the current font size of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has getFontSize method see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/editor.js#L481